# Neo4J - Simple cypher query

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Assume there are two node entities:

```
public class Account extends BaseEntity
{
...
@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type = "HAS_ROLE")
private Set<Role> roles = Sets.newHashSet();
...
}

public class Role extends BaseEntity
{
...
}
```

In my repository, I have a Query that should get all Accounts by a given Role:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends GraphRepository<Account>
{
    @Query("START account=node:Account(0) MATCH account-[:HAS_ROLE]->({0}) return account")
    Iterable<Account> findByRole(Role role);
}
```

But this query doesn't work, when I use this method in my test case I get the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement START account=node:Account(0) MATCH account-[:HAS_ROLE]->({0}) return account; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement START account=node:Account(0) MATCH account-[:HAS_ROLE]->({0}) return account; nested exception is expected string

As it seems, there is something wrong with my query, but I don't know what, and could't figure it out yet...
Could anyone provide some help?

Comment: Please specify the version of Neo4j used, it IS important.

Comment: I'm using neo4j 1.8.M07, spring-data-neo4j 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Please accept an answer or answer (and accept) your own. It looks like you've got a solution ("I changed it to ... and everything is fine") and it would be good to get this question closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your query like this. You already know the Role so use it as a STARTing point.

```
@Query("START role=node({0}) MATCH account-[:HAS_ROLE]->role return account")
Iterable<Account> findByRole(Role role);
```

Answer (score 0):

Markus,

You should migrate to Neo4j 1.8 GA and SDN 2.1.0 RELEASE.

Also, what does your BaseEntity and Role classes look like?

Regards,

Lasse

Comment: Hey Lasse, thanks for your help..I switched to the current releases, but my query seemed to be wrong. I changed it to "START role=node({0}) MATCH account-[:HAS_ROLE]->role return account" (Thanks Michael Hunger), and everything is fine...Really have to do some Neo4j homework...

Answer (score 0):

How about using this query?

```
START account=node(*) MATCH (account)-[r:HAS_ROLE]->() return account
```

it will be return all account has 'HAS_ROLE'